# Illegal initializer for 'java.lang.String' io.cucumber.java @After annotation

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

In Hooks.java after changing imports from

```
//import cucumber.api.java.After;
//import cucumber.api.java.Before;
```

To:

```
import io.cucumber.java.*;
```

Seeing below error for the piece of code:

```
@After({"@Phase1, @Phase2, @Phase3"})
```

Illegal initializer for 'java.lang.String'

Comment: What is Phase1, Phase2, Phase3? it seems that you are initializing an String as an array or something that isn't an String, check this out https://coderanch.com/t/517298/java/Illegal-initializer-java-lang-String

Answer (score 3):

[Conditional hooks](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#hooks) use a [tag expression](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#tag-expressions) which is a single string. So you have to use `@After("@Phase1 or @Phase2 or @Phase3")`.